# Store Credit update email is not populatig the balance in magento

Tags: php, magento

We are using magento enterprise edition, i have store credit update transactional email template, but when customer get an email they are not getting the balance.

here is my code in transactional email.

```
<body style="background: #F6F6F6; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="background: #F6F6F6; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0">
                    <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="center">
<br>
<br>
<br>
                                <a href="{{store url=""}}" style="color:#b9864d;"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" border="0"/></a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <h1 style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 22px; margin: 0 0 11px 0;">Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},</h1>

                      We have updated your account on <a href="{{store url=""}}">{{store url=""}}</a> and you have credit which you may use for future purchases.</p><br>
                      Your Store Credit balance is now {{var balance}}</p><br>
                    To view your store credit, login to your account to access your dashboard. In the dashboard, you will find the 'My Gift Cards and Store Credit' section. You may click-through to view your credit balance and history.</p><br>
                  To use your store credit, login to your account and proceed with checkout. In the 'Payment Information' step at checkout, you may select 'Use Store Credit' to apply to your purchase.
                      </td>
                </tr>
```

in the email always i am getting

> Your Store Credit balance is now: is empty.

how can i get the store credit balance.

I really appreciate your help.